# Discord.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'prefix' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I get the following error...

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
(node:8232) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prefix' of undefined
```

When using a command from my bot. I think the issue is with the bot's main file.
The following code block is where I believe the error is coming from.

```js
function startsWithPrefix(str, prefix) { if (str.slice(0, prefix.length).toLowerCase() == prefix.toLowerCase()) return true; }



// Execute when the bot sees a message
client.on('message', async msg => {
    // Initialize guild settings on first message
    if (msg.guild && !Settings[msg.guild.id]) {
        const pool = new Pool();
        try {
            const res = await pool.query('SELECT prefix FROM settings WHERE guild_id = $1', [msg.guild.id]);
            if (res.rows[0]) { Settings[msg.guild.id] = res.rows[0]; }
            else {
                Settings[msg.guild.id] = {
                    prefix: 'a!' // Default setting
                };
            }
        } catch (err) { console.log(err.stack); }
        finally { pool.end(); }
    }
    // Exit if msg doesn't start with prefix
    if (msg.guild && !startsWithPrefix(msg.content, Settings[msg.guild.id].prefix)) { return; }
    // Exit if msg was sent by a bot
    if (msg.author.bot) { return; }
    // Exit + Reply with a helpful message if msg was dm-ed to this bot
    if (msg.channel.type == 'dm') { return await msg.reply(`I got nothin' for ya buddy :pensive:\nI think you meant to type that in the **Among Us LFG** server :+1:`); }


    // Separate the command from the arguments
    const words = msg.content.split(' ');
    const cmdName = words[0].toLowerCase().slice(Settings[msg.guild.id].prefix.length);
    const cmd = client.cmds.get(cmdName) || client.cmds.get(client.aliases.get(cmdName));
    const args = words.slice(1);

    // Run the command
    if (cmd) cmd.run(client, msg, args);
});

// Start the bot
client.login(discordToken);
```

**EDIT: seems like Settings[msg.guild.id] is undefined, However I define it as**

```
let Settings = {};
exports.Settings = Settings;
```

at the start of the code dunno whats wrong

Comment: Seems that `Settings[msg.guild.id]` is undefined. Could you please try to `console.log(Settings[msg.guild.id])` and send us the output?

Comment: oh yeah its undefined when i logged it weird the bot used to work fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to define the prefix with a const like this:

```js
const prefix = '!'
```